# React class component: avoid undesirable state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to create a small service that would count the number of business days between 2 dates. I have 2 date input fields for dates, and a button, on click it runs a loop, excluding Saturdays and Sundays, and will return a number of days.

I initialize both dates in the state, and I have `onChange` handling functions for both input fields, which set state dates according to the user input. Then, I use these values from the state in the abovementioned loop, and the exit condition is when the first date equals the second.

It works well for the first time. Then, the date values in the state are updated. I figured that's due to the fact I'm not creating a new variable in the `handleCalculateButtonClick` function - when I do `const firstDate = this.state.firstDate`, and change the `firstDate`, it also changes the value in the state.

I tried to overcome it by creating a reset function on another button click - `handleResetButtonClick`, where I wanted the dates in state to be set to something neutral, like current date - however, it doesn't seem to work

Here is how the code looks:

```
import { React, PureComponent } from 'react';

class CountBetweenDatesComponent extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currDate: new Date(),
            firstDate: new Date(),
            secondDate: new Date(),
            todayExcluded: false,
            saturdaysIncluded: false
        };
        this.setFirstDate = this.setFirstDate.bind(this);
        this.setSecondDate = this.setSecondDate.bind(this);
        this.handleCalculateButtonClick = this.handleCalculateButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.excludeToday = this.excludeToday.bind(this);
        this.includeSaturdays = this.includeSaturdays.bind(this);
        this.handleResetButtonClick = this.handleResetButtonClick.bind(this);
        
    }

    setFirstDate = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            firstDate: new Date(event.target.value)
        })
    }

    setSecondDate = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            secondDate: new Date(event.target.value)
        })
    }

    compareDates = (firstDate, secondDate) => {
        if (firstDate > secondDate) {
            throw new Error('Please enter the earliest of 2 dates in the first input box')
        } else if (firstDate === secondDate) {
            throw new Error('The dates are the same. Please choose later date in the second box')
        }
    }

    handleCalculateButtonClick = () => {
        const firstDate = this.state.firstDate;
        const secondDate = this.state.secondDate;
        console.log('handle', firstDate);
        const firstDateCompareValue = firstDate.getTime();
        const secondDateCompareValue = secondDate.getTime();
        try {
            this.compareDates(firstDateCompareValue, secondDateCompareValue)
        } catch(e) {
            window.alert(e);
        }
        
        if ( this.state.todayExcluded) {
            firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 1)
        } 
        let numberOfDays = 0;
        while (firstDate.getTime() !== secondDate.getTime()) {
            firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 1);

            if (this.state.saturdaysIncluded) {
                if ( firstDate.getDay() === 6) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    numberOfDays++;
                }
            } else {
                if ( firstDate.getDay() === 0 || firstDate.getDay() === 6) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    numberOfDays++;
                }
            }   
        }
                
        console.log(numberOfDays);
    }

    handleResetButtonClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            firstDate: new Date(), 
            secondDate: new Date()
        });
        console.log(this.state.firstDate)
    }

    excludeToday = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                todayExcluded: !this.state.todayExcluded
            }
        )
    }

    includeSaturdays = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                saturdaysIncluded: !this.state.saturdaysIncluded
            }
        )
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Count business days between 2 dates</h4>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Exclude today <input type="checkbox" id="today" name="today" onChange={ this.excludeToday }></input></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Count with Saturdays <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="saturday" onChange={ this.includeSaturdays }></input></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>From: <input type="date" id="firstDate" name="firstDate"onChange={ this.setFirstDate }></input></label>
                    <label>To: <input type="date" id="secondDate" name="secondDate" onChange={ this.setSecondDate }></input></label>
                    <button onClick={ this.handleCalculateButtonClick }>Calculate</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.handleResetButtonClick }>Reset</button>
                </div>
                <p> working days between these dates</p>
            </div>
        )
    }   

}

export default CountBetweenDatesComponent
```

I tried some ways of having initial state variable outside of class, and use it - what I achieved so far was either the result was the same, or when I used a getter for the initial state, the onChange handlers for date input fields did not change the state variables to what the user put into it.

What would be the best way to achieve the desired outcome - make `firstDate` and `secondDate` state vars to be updatable only from the onChange functions, but still be able to loop through a date objects to count the number of working days?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this you have to create a new date object like this:

```
const firstDate = new Date(this.state.firstDate.getTime());
const secondDate = new Date(this.state.secondDate.getTime());
```

As you pointed out by creating new date object you are avoiding this behavior.

Working [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-benji-lkrtip?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The proposed solution didn't really work, as creating new object basically led to creating a new reference to the object, thus modifying both. I solved the problem by turning the `firstDate` and `secondDate` into strings, and then turning them back to Date where it's needed